# SAPUI5 change row content and write back to table

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I have a table which is bound to an XML model.

```
 var oModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
 oModel.loadData("http://localhost/xxxxx");

 var oTable = this.getView().byId("TableId");
 oTable.setModel(oModel);
        oTable.bindRows({
            path: "/tageventlist/tagevent",
        })
```

I am reading the rows in my controller simply like this:

```
var oItems = this.byId("TableId").getRows();
```

Now I loop through the items and I need to change the contents of 2 fields:

```
for (var i = 0; i < oItems.length; i++) {
     oItems[i].mAggregations.cells[1].mProperties.unit = 'NewUnit';
     oItems[i].mAggregations.cells[0].mProperties.title = 'NewTitle;
 }
```

I can see the changed values in the debugger but how can I write the changed values back to the table? 
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the values in the model, you can loop over the rows to get the binding context. The binding context will give you the binding path which can be used to set properties in the model.

```
var oItems = this.byId("TableId").getRows();
var oModel = this.oTable.getModel();

oItems.forEach(function(oItem){
    var oContext = oItem.getBindingContext();
    oModel.setProperty(oContext.getPath()+"/unit ","NewUnit");
    oModel.setProperty(oContext.getPath()+"/title  ","NewTitle");
});
```

Comment: Better way is `oModel.setProperty("unit ","NewUnit", oContext);`

Comment: @ДаниилПереверзев This code was valid was valid for an older version of SPAUI5. Feel free to update it if it's outdated or there's a better way to do it.